# How can I use ckeditor5 in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to implement WYSIWYG editor in my angular application v10. The editor is [this](https://ckeditor.com/blog/best-wysiwyg-editor-for-angular-react/). Now when I am implementing it on plane component(without angular material) it works fine. The problem starts when I want it to implement it using Angular Material under mat-form-field. Here is my code

```
<form class="example-form">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Request Title*</mat-label>
  <input matInput  value="">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="mat-editor" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Request Description / Requirements*</mat-label>
 <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor> 
 </mat-form-field>
```

The Request Title input box appears fine but when it comes to Request Description field which is the WYSIWYG editor, it throws error in the console. The error is **mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.** When I just insert normal input box like below. The editor is displayed but it looses focus as soon as I click on it and focus goes to the input box which i added.

```
<mat-form-field class="mat-editor" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Request Description / Requirements*</mat-label>
 <input matInput  value=""> 
  <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor> 
 </mat-form-field>
```

I even added the tag matInput  in ckeditor like below, but it didn't work.

```
  <ckeditor matInput   [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

I googled the problem and found one solution [here](https://github.com/wynfred/mat-contenteditable). But it didn't solve my problem.

```
 <ckeditor matCkeditor   [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

This is how it is displayed when I add dummy textbox within  tag. But focus went to the dummy text box as soon as I click the editor to write something into it.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlQPM.png)

Comment: `<ckeditor formControlName="cdEditor" [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor> `
Have you tried to add formControlName property to ckeditor tag?

Comment: <mat-form-field> is a component used to wrap several Angular Material components and apply common Text field styles such as the underline, floating label, and hint messages. Since CKEditor is not an Angular Material Text field. you need to make it straight, what CKEditor offers.

Comment: So is there a way we can use this editor and wrap it under <mat-form-field>?

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always" [hideRequiredMarker]="'true'">
  <mat-label>Message (please edit as needed)</mat-label>
  <textarea matInput #messageInput placeholder="Enter message" [(ngModel)]="model.message" required
    style="display: none;"></textarea>
  <ckeditor (focus)="onFocusElement()" (focusout)="onFocusoutElement()"
    [(ngModel)]="model.message" id="myckeditor1" #myckeditor1="ngModel" name="myckeditor1" [config]="CkeConfig"
    debounce="500">
  </ckeditor>
</mat-form-field>
```

on ts file

```
onFocusElement() {
    this.messageClass = 'msg-ckeditor';
  }

onFocusoutElement() {
    if (Utility.isNullorUndefined(this.model.message) || this.model.message.trim() === '') {
      this.messageClass = 'msg-ckeditor-error';
    } else {
      this.messageClass = '';
    }
  }
```

and on css side

```
.msg-ckeditor .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: #01a79d;
}
.msg-ckeditor-error .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: #f44336;
}
```

and it worked for me with ckeditor v1.2.6. If you find better way to solve than please share.